# Sunburst chart in angular using highcharts not showing different colors

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display a sunburst chart using Highcharts in Angular. The chart is displaying, but the problem is with the colors. I've mentioned an array of colors, but the chart only shows the very first color from the array. Can someone please help me what I'm doing wrong here?

**Below is my code:**

```
this.chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

      chart: {
        type: 'sunburst',
        height: '100%'
      },
      colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce',
        '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'], 
      title: {
          text: 'PSec GEARS Function Usage'
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: 'Top 10 Functions used as % per User for the last Month'
      },
      credits: {
          enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '',
        pointFormat: 'The population of <b>{point.name}</b> is <b>{point.value}</b>'
      }, 

      series: [{
        type: "sunburst",
        data: this.dataValues,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            format: '{point.name}',
            filter: {
                property: 'innerArcLength',
                operator: '>',
                value: 16
            },
            rotationMode: 'circular'
        },
        
        levels: [{
          level: 1,
          dataLabels: {
            filter: {
              property: 'outerArcLength',
              operator: '>',
              value: 64
            }
          }
        }, {
          level: 2,
          colorByPoint: true
        },
        {
          level: 3,
          colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: -0.5
          }
        }, {
          level: 4,
          colorVariation: {
            key: 'brightness',
            to: 0.5
          }
        }]
      }]
    });
```

**This is an image of the output chart I get:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the data in the code you sent, so it's hard to say what exactly you're doing wrong, but the data structure in the sunburst chart should look like this:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'sunburst'
    },
    colors: ['#2f7ed8', '#0d233a', '#8bbc21', '#910000', '#1aadce',
      '#492970', '#f28f43', '#77a1e5', '#c42525', '#a6c96a'], 
    series: [{
      type: "sunburst",
      data: [
        {
          id: '0.0',
          parent: '',
          name: 'Main'
        }, {
          id: '1.1',
          parent: '0.0',
          name: 'A'
        }, {
          id: '1.2',
          parent: '0.0',
          name: 'B'
        },
        {
          id: '1.3',
          parent: '0.0',
          name: 'C'
        },
        {
          id: '2.1',
          parent: '1.1',
          name: 'A1',
          value: 10
        }, {
          id: '2.2',
          parent: '1.1',
          name: 'A2',
          value: 5
        },
        {
          id: '2.3',
          parent: '1.2',
          name: 'B1',
          value: 12
        },
        {
          id: '2.4',
          parent: '1.2',
          name: 'B2',
          value: 8
        },
        {
          id: '2.5',
          parent: '1.3',
          name: 'C1',
          value: 15
        },
        {
          id: '2.5',
          parent: '1.3',
          name: 'C2',
          value: 7
        },
        
        {
          id: '2.5',
          parent: '1.3',
          name: 'C3',
          value: 11
        },
      ],
      levels: [{
        level: 1,
        dataLabels: {
          filter: {
            property: 'outerArcLength',
            operator: '>',
            value: 64
          }
        }
      }, {
        level: 2,
        colorByPoint: true
      },
      {
        level: 3,
        colorVariation: {
          key: 'brightness',
          to: -0.5
        }
      }, {
        level: 4,
        colorVariation: {
          key: 'brightness',
          to: 0.5
        }
      }]
    }]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sunburst.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

**Official demo**: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sunburst.data

Comment: Hi @Michal, thanks for your reply, Yes the data structure was my problem. I didn't know that sunburst required `id` and `parent` properties.